# How to avoid synology file operations being routed through macos host?

Tags: macos, file-transfer, finder, smb, synology

When I use Finder (or Path Finder) on macos to do file operations (copy/move) on my Synology the files get first downloaded to my macos machine and then uploaded again to Synology.

E.g. : I move file F from Synology://FOLDER1 to Synology://FOLDER2. Finder downloads F from FOLDER1 and uploads it to FOLDER2.

I use smb to connect to my Synology.

How can I avoid this and do intra-Synology file operations without the files being routed through my macos machine?

**EDIT:**

I´d like to do the file ops from withon macos/finder. Using the Synology FileStation web interface or ssh´ing into the box should be avoided.

Comment: Do it using the File Station inside Synology? You can "Map a drive" from in there, to map the other Synology, and transfer files straight there. Or if you are familiar with command line, you can enable SSH and go straight from there

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I forgot to mention that I´d like to do the file ops from within macos/finder.

Comment: I don't think it is possible as you are doing a Mac OS X action of copying / moving from folder to folder (even if it is a remote folder). If you want to avoid the Mac from doing the work, then you need to tell Synology to do the work (either from web interface, or SSH). The good thing about doing it via SSH it can be scripted and you can simply run a shell script that you prepared.